# Can I change the app icons?

Tags: applications, app-icons

Is there any way I can change the icons (displayed on the home screen) for apps on my Android device?

(Apps includes both system apps and apps downloaded from play store)

Comment: You can't change throughout the device, but [this  app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jy.iconchanger.ad) worked for me on my first device on KitKat, to change on desktop. Haven't used it since

Comment: I changed app icons on my launcher by editing launcher's database with `sqlite3` CLI program. However that's too complex for an average user so I'm not posting it here. `Update layout Set icon = ReadFile("new.png") Where _id = "xxx";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As beeshyams has already written in the comment, it is possible with this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jy.iconchanger.ad).

Alternatively, another launcher can be installed. Many launchers (Like [Nova](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher)) can be customized with various themes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change icons and edit the size, placement, color virtually anything i suggest a launcher. go to the play store and download Nova Launcher. install it and play around with its many options. As you will see editing your entire Android experience can be done with this launcher. However you need tp go back to the play store and down load some Icon packs. I cute icons I downloaded upbeat monsters icon pack. 
after it is down loaded go into Nova settings and choose look and feel. a list of icon packs will be listed choose upbeat monsters and it will automatically change them. for more editing you can long press any icon and it will give you options to edit if you pick upbeat monsters again you will get a ton of icons to choose from.
This is only one example of many launchers and thousands of icons